# Why can't I reduce to a different type in RxJs 6?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The example below doesn't work as a straight conversion from the chained operator in version 5. It gives a Typescript compiler error.

```js
from([1, 2]).pipe(
    reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc + ' ';
    }, '')
);
```

> Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.   Types of
>   parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>         Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. [2345]

Comment: What does not work exactly , i mean what is the desired output ?

Comment: It doesn't compile in Typescript: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<number, string>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<number>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. [2345]

Comment: What is exactly the expected behaviour of this code? It looks like that it's only adding an space `' '` for every element... Shouldn't you be using the `curr` value?

Comment: @JosepJoestar - No. It's an indicative example only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a working version

```
from([1, 2])
  .pipe(
    reduce<number, string>(
      (acc, curr) => {
        return acc + ' ';
      }, '')
  ).subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x);
  });
```

Now a bit of explanation, the problem here is coming from this line (which is from the rxjs source) and defines the function signature(types)

```
export function reduce<T>(accumulator: (acc: T, value: T, index: number) => T, seed?: T): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
```

So in your case because you are not defying types explicitly, rxjs thinks that the `acc` and the `value` are from the same type (`number` in your case, because you are passing array of numbers)

By defying explicitly the types of the function arguments we are fixing this problem, because we are kind of helping rxjs/ts to use the appropriate function signature that is below (this way no erros will be thrown)

```
export function reduce<T, R>(accumulator: (acc: R, value: T, index: number) => R, seed?: R): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

[Here is the `reduce` source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/reduce.ts)

If we have to sum it up, the problem is that rxjs/ts needs some explicit help with the typings.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: was answered before OP described he had issues with TypeScript

You need to import RxJs and subscribe to the stream:

```js
rxjs.from([1, 2]).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc + ' ' + curr;
    }, '')
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, that's not the reason - sorry, I can understand the confusion. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have two different kinds of Observable library that come from separate copies of RxJS (maybe from an older version). Take a look at the `package.json`, the `package.lock.json` or `node_modules` folder for duplicated packages by doing `$ npm ls rxjs` or simply remove this package and perform another fresh install. Let me know if it works!